# Dropdownlists creates postback on key changes in IE

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have created a label and a dropdownlist. The label has the dropdownlist as associated id.
If I click on the label and then uses the mouse up or down the dropdownlist creates a postback for each click. This is quite anoying and doesn't happen if you click on the dropdownlist and uses key-up or key-down, or if you uses another browser than IE.

Is it possibel to fix this, so you can use key-up and key-down without causing a postback, and first on the enter-key creates the postback (as it does if you click on the dropdownlist and not label)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `DropDownList.AutoPostBack` to `false`.

Comment: I don't want to disable autopostback. Like I wrote, I would like to be able use the key-up and down and then use the enter-key to cause the postback. This works if you click on the dropdownlist, but not on the label.

Comment: That's the autopostback behaviour - http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/189-AutoPostBack-What-How-works.aspx. I'd suggest writing some javascript to fire when the return key is pressed on the dropdownlist which calls __doPostBack.

Comment: I choose to you use the javascript with __doPostBack, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set the `AutoPostBack` property to false.
See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx).